# Table with vertical text, and \multicolumn

Tags: tables

I want to make a table which looks like the one below:

[image: required table]

I tried this code but it gives me something weird

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{my table}
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|l|}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Household}\end{sideways}}}} & \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}}} & \multirow{10}[20]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}Peer pressure/prestige among parents \\
\cmidrule{5-5}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}Economic status \\
\cmidrule{5-5}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}Value placed on education \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{5-5}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Child}\end{sideways}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}Aspirations \\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{5-5}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{9}[18]{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & Ability \\
\cmidrule{5-5}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & Academic performance \\
\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{5-5}    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}[10]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949}\textcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Schooling/ teaching quality}\end{sideways}}}} &       & Exam-orientation, emphasis on scores \\
\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{5-5}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{}} &       &       & Inadequacy of schooling \\
\cmidrule{5-5}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{20.355em}|}{Burden of non-academic tasks on teachers} \\
\cmidrule{5-5}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{20.355em}|}{Recruitment/promotion unlinked to teaching performance} \\
\cmidrule{4-5}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{3}[6]{*}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949}\textcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}{\begin{sideways}\textbf{Cultural/ other factors}\end{sideways}}}} & Direct shirking/corruption by teachers \\
\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{5-5}          &       & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{p{20.355em}|}{Labour market premium for elite colleges/professions} \\
\cmidrule{5-5}          &       &       &       & Herd mentality \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Could someone help?

Comment: A full MWE starting from \begin{document} and including the packages used would be useful.  For example. both colortbl and tabu use \rowcolor.

Comment: Maybe you could use \rotatebox{90}{...}? But a full MWE would be nice to test it.

Comment: Have edited the post to include MWE

Comment: @PGupta your example does not compile as it is. Maybe some packages are missing?

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, there was an error in it. Have edited the MWE. It should compile now. But the text overflows from the cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another nicematrix!

Not a surprise: the `nicematrix` package by itself provides all the necessary elements for this table. Moreover, the code is clean and simple.

Frankly, I like a tool that allows me to spend more time filling in content than formatting.

The main command used, `\Block`, allows  the identification and format of the multi row/column cells.
(The command `\Block{}` creates a monoblock cell that allows the use of `\\` inside, thus cutting the line where you want it instead of relying  on the width of the column. See the before the last row.)

Notice that all cell are vertically centered.

The package  requires two compilations  (when the formatting is changed),  which is sometimes mentioned as inconvenient.
It is not if you develop the table in a separate file and then put the file in the main document in the final stages.

[image: x3]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}    

\begin{NiceTabular}{|wc{25pt}wc{25pt} wc{25pt} wc{25pt} |l|}[%
    cell-space-top-limit = 7pt,
    cell-space-bottom-limit = 7pt,
    code-before = \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{1-1}{4-1},
    code-before = \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{4-2}{7-2},
    code-before = \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{7-3}{11-3},
    code-before = \rectanglecolor{gray!15}{11-4}{17-4}, 
    ]
     \hline
    \rotate\Block[draw=black]{4-1}{\bfseries Household} & \Block{3-1}{}& \Block{6-1}{} & \Block{10-1}{} & Peer pressure/prestige among parents\\\cline{5-5}
    & & & & Economic status \\\cline{5-5}
    & & & & Value placed on education\\\cline{5-5}
    &\rotate \Block[draw=black]{4-1}{\bfseries Child  }& & & Aspirations \\\cline{5-5}
    \Block{9-1}{}&  & & & Ability \\\cline{5-5}
    & & & & Academic performance \\\cline{5-5}
    & &\rotate\Block[draw=black]{5-1}{\bfseries Schooling/  teaching quality}& & Exam-orientation, emphasis on scores \\\cline{5-5}
    & \Block{6-1}{} & & & Inadequacy of schooling \\\cline{5-5}
    & & & & \Block{}{Burden od non--academic tasks on \\ teachers} \\\cline{5-5}
    & & & &  \Block{}{Recruitment/promotion unlinked to \\teaching performance} \\\cline{5-5}
    & & &\rotate\Block[draw=black]{3-1}{\bfseries Cultural/ \\ \bfseries other factors}  & Direct shirking/corruption by teachers \\\cline{5-5}
    & &  \Block{2-1}{} & & \Block{}{Labour market premium for elite \\ colleges/professions} \\\cline{5-5}
    & & & &  Herd mentality \\
     \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks really neat, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With the help of `nicematrix` (needs version 5.8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 3pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c | p{7.25cm}|}
\cline{5-5}
\Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{4-1}{\rotate Household}  & &  &                      & Peer pressure/prestige among parents                   \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Economic status                                        \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Value placed on education                              \\ \cline{5-5}
   & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{4-1}{\rotate Child} & &                         & Aspirations                                            \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Ability                                                \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Academic performance                                   \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{5-1}{\rotate Schooling/\\ teaching quality} & & Exam-orientation, emphasis on scores                   \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Inadequacy of schooling                                \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Burden of non-academic tasks on teachers               \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Recruitment/promotion unlinked to teaching performance \\ \cline{5-5} 
   & & & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{3-1}{\rotate Cultural/\\ other factors}     & Direct shirking/corruption by teachers                 \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Labour market premium for elite colleges/professions   \\ \cline{5-5}
   & & &                                                                                & Herd mentality                                         \\ \cline{5-5}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a small variation of leandriis' answer. I have used the key `hvlines` (provided by `nicematrix`) to draw all the rules. Since I don't want interior rules in the first four columns, I have put a global `\Block` for these four columns: `\Block{-4}{}` (the syntax `-4` means `?-4` that is to say 4 columns and all the remaining rows).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c >{\arraybackslash}p{7.25cm}}[hvlines]
\Block{-4}{}
\Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{4-1}{\rotate Household}  & &  &                      & Peer pressure/prestige among parents                   \\
   & & &                                                                                & Economic status                                        \\
   & & &                                                                                & Value placed on education                              \\
   & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{4-1}{\rotate Child} & &                         & Aspirations                                            \\
   & & &                                                                                & Ability                                                \\
   & & &                                                                                & Academic performance                                   \\
   & & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{5-1}{\rotate Schooling/\\ teaching quality} & & Exam-orientation, emphasis on scores                   \\
   & & &                                                                                & Inadequacy of schooling                                \\
   & & &                                                                                & Burden of non-academic tasks on teachers               \\
   & & &                                                                                & Recruitment/promotion unlinked to teaching performance \\ 
   & & & \Block[fill=lightgray, draw=black]{3-1}{\rotate Cultural/\\ other factors}     & Direct shirking/corruption by teachers                 \\
   & & &                                                                                & Labour market premium for elite colleges/professions   \\
   & & &                                                                                & Herd mentality                                         \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: All the answer with nicematrix :-))))

Comment: `\Block{-4}{}` definitely is an interesting idea. Using it in combination with `hvlines` shortens the code a lot.